# How to instantiate a .NET class in PHP which has a parameterized constructor?

Tags: php, .net, oop, constructor, instance

I want to use a class of .NET in PHP and am using the `DOTNET` class of PHP for this purpose. I want to  instantiate a class which has a parameterized constructor.

```
$e = new DOTNET($full_assembly_string, $full_class_name);
```

How do I pass constructor arguments through this API?

Comment: And what? You have error?

Comment: @u_mulder No, it's simply unclear how to pass constructor arguments for the .NET class through this API.

Comment: [This page](http://blog.zitec.com/2012/handling-net-assemblies-in-php/) says "Another issue is that you cannot pass parameters to a class constructor within a DLL".  Sounds like it might be a limitation of the php dotnet functionality.  Are you able to alter the .Net code to instead create an instance of a factory class which has a method on it that constructs the object you're really after?

Comment: @AtifMajeed If my answer help you, you can check as correct and/or upvote. :-)

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer (Without getting influenced by your comment). And if you see he has multiple questions where there is a possible correct answer you also may/can notice him that he can also accept answers on his other questions if the is such an answer

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks, I always learn with your comments ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not possible do that

There are few issues when doing this integration that you might want to consider:

1. Public methods

Just like the PHP manual says, the returned object is an overloaded object which makes PHP unaware of the public methods the object might contain. So, if you var_dump it, you will see nothing but an empty array. That is why the inner DLL class structure mus be known prior to calling it.

Luckily for us there is another tool specialized for this job shipped with the .NET framework called ildasm.exe. It is located next to gacutil.exe under
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\ or c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin.
To load and display the DLL structure simply call “ildasm.exe \path\to\your.dll“.

**2. Parameters
Another issue is that you cannot pass parameters to a class constructor within a DLL.**

3. Data types

Being two different programming language, we have different data types involved. This being said, you will have to make sure the DLL class methods return data types that PHP understands (mostly strings, ints, booleans, etc). In case your methods needs to return an array list or a more complicated structure, you might want to consider JSON for encoding.

Read more at

> http://blog.zitec.com/2012/handling-net-assemblies-in-php/